# MySQL - prevent duplicates for multiple insert statement without using a unique index

Tags: mysql, sql

I need to do a multiple insert statement and I need to prevent duplicate rows **without using the primary key or any other unique index**. The to-be-inserted rows need to check two (or more) columns for equality, then prevent the insert if all columns match at least one row already within the table. The ideal solution would be to only use one MySQL insert statement.

For example, there is a table with one row already inserted:

```
INSERT INTO `table1` (`a`, `b`, `c`)
  VALUES ('1', '2', 'foo');
```

This is the data that still needs to be inserted:

```
INSERT INTO `table1` (`a`, `b`, `c`)
  VALUES ('A', 'B', 'C'), ('1', '2', 'bar'), ('D', 'E', 'F');
```

How can you check columns a and b for duplicates so that ('1', '2', 'bar') does not get inserted while both ('A', 'B', 'C') and ('D', 'E', 'F') do get inserted?

Comment: Does (1,3,bar) collide with (1,2,foo)?  How about (2,2,bar)? What are the exact criteria you use to determine a duplicate row?

Comment: Asking how to prevent duplicate rows in a RDMS without using indexes is sort of like saying, "I need to drive my car to New York. It has a flat tire and I don't want to repair it. So, what's the best route to New York if I'm driving on my rim?"

Comment: @Ollie Jones I agree completely. My only solution right now would be to create a unique index on the columns and use `ON DUPLICATE KEY` in the insert. My problem is that I cannot confirm if those columns should always be unique, since its data/code I did not write myself.

Comment: The actual criteria is somewhat generic in this example for a reason. I am more interested in what the syntax would be for solving this problem than what the specific details for the comparisons.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `insert . . . select`:

```
INSERT INTO `table1` (`a`, `b`, `c`)
    select t.*
    from (select 'a' as a, 'b' as b, 'c' as c union all
          select '1', '2', 'bar' union all
          select 'd', 'e', 'f'
         ) t
    where not exists (select 1 from table1 t1 where t1.a = t.a and t1.b = t.b);
```

Comment: This is a bit messy, but it's exactly what I was looking for. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

only way is to check for existence of the row with the values.
It is better to create a primary key, so that you can use INSERT IGNORE

```
if not exists ( select * from table1 where a = '1' and b ='2' and c ='bar')
   insert into table1 ('1','2', 'bar')
```

Comment: `IF NOT EXIST` is something I have been looking into. How would this syntax translate to a multi-insert statement.